# Как вернуть значение из асинхронного запроса?

Tags: javascript

Как можно вернуть значение из этой  функции?
После того как данный код сработал, он возвращает промис, а данные вытянуть я не знаю как

```
 async function get() {
       let result = await fetch('https://api.coindesk.com/v1/bpi/currentprice.json');
       return await result.json()
   }
   console.log(get());
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Примерно так:

```
 async function get() {
       let result = await fetch('https://api.coindesk.com/v1/bpi/currentprice.json');
       return await result.json();
   }

(async function() {
   console.log(await get());
})()
```

либо

```
async function get() {
   let result = await fetch('https://api.coindesk.com/v1/bpi/currentprice.json');
   return await result.json();
}

get().then(response => { console.log(response) })
```

Comment: Понял, спасибо)